# Встроенные компоненты Jquery-UI не подключаются в шапке Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Хочу воспользоваться встроеннымии (wp-includes) компонентами Jquery-UI на сайте. 
имеется такой код для подключения:

```
function html5blank_header_scripts()

{

    if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script('conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
        wp_enqueue_script('conditionizr'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js', array(), '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr'); // Enqueue it!

        //wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
        //wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');

        wp_register_script('semantic', get_template_directory_uri() . '/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('semantic');
    }

}
add_action('init', 'html5blank_header_scripts');
```

Специально не убирал лишнее - например, Semantic UI и остальное нормально подключается, однако jquery-ui компоненты нет: они просто не присутствуют в списке подключаемых скриптов.

Было испробовано несколько разных способов, в том числе и подключение через явное указание пути в каталоге /wp-includes в функции wp_register_script, так же указывал зависимости, но тщетно, нормально работает только jquery, который подключается ядром самого Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню, когда приходилось сталкиваться с такой проблемой я отключал jquery (deregister и dequeue) и включал ui.

Должно работать все, потому что "jQuery UI is a widget and interaction library built on top of the jQuery JavaScript Library that you can use to build highly interactive web applications".

Comment: Н-невнимательность. При редактироваинии удалил из footer.php вызов wp_footer() в результате все подключаемые вещи отсутствовали. Спасибо, что нашли время и постарались ответить на вопрос с заведомо недостаточной информацией, отмечу ответом.